# read data from file and use the data as multiple checkboxes in extended choice parameter in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a file with a list of cases that i would like to be able to use as multiple selection check box in my Jenkins project.

example: jenkins.properties

```
case01_successful_Connection
case02_successful_Disconnection
case03_unsuccessful_Connection
...
```

The list of cases (in the file) can be from time to time get bigger or smaller!

So, how can Jenkins now read those cases and create during "Build with parameters" the needed check boxes so that the user can select or not the cases?

How should the properties file look like?
Which plug-in should i use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[Extended Choice Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin)** plugin

- Setup new parameter, let's call it `mychoice`
- Select "Type" as `Checkboxes`
- Choose a "Delimeter", for example `,`
- Under "Choose Source for Value", select `Property File`
- Specify location of property file, it has to be an absolute location, not relative.
- Specify "Property Key" that's in the property file, for example "mychoice_values"
- Type the following in your property file:
  `mychoice_values=choice1,choice2,choice3`

Every time "Build with parameters" is invoked, it will read that property file, find line that starts with `mychoice_values`, and will present 3 checkboxes called `choice1`, `choice2`, and `choice3`.

If the property file changes, new choices will be presented

Comment: Thanks, this does the work! Quick question, i am trying to use delimiter "|" instead of ",". But this does not work, actually not even ";" is separating the values! Do you have any solution to this?

Comment: Values in the property file have to be separated by comma `,` The "Delimeter" field is for delimiting the values (if multiple choices are selected) for the actual `mychoice` variable

Comment: Hope my last question about this matter. How can i set value `None` if i don't select any of the check boxes (from the choice1,choice2,choice3)? So the `mychoice` should be None in this case

Comment: Can't really. The value of `mychoice` will simply be empty `mychoice=`. It's  up to your handling script to parse it correctly. You can setup default checkboxes, but those won't be mutually exclusive though.

Answer (score 0):

With the answer from Slav and my additional settings I managed to solve my question:

In addition:
1. i added "Default Value" = `None`
2. i added in the property file: `mychoice_values=choice1,choice2,choice3,None` (`None`)

With the above settings 4 check boxes are created and by default the `None` check box is pre-selected!

It is not perfect the solution, because the user has to uncheck the `None` box if he checks other boxes! Prefect would be, if `None` check box would be unchecked automatically when other check boxes are selected!!!